# Trying to generate unique permutation every second

Tags: javascript

When I run the code I want unique permutations to be listed every second
not repeated like if you run the code several words repeat and I don't want that please thank you.

```
            function shuffle(array) {
                  let currentIndex = array.length,
               temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  //             While there remain elements to shuffle...
              while (0 !== currentIndex) {

               // Pick a remaining element...
             randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
               currentIndex -= 1;

             // And swap it with the current element.
               temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
             array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
               array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
                   }

              return array;
                }

              let d = ["d", "e", "a", "d"];

             setInterval(function() {
           console.log(shuffle(d).join(""))
             }, 1000)
```

Comment: Use permutation algorithm then and you will have 120 (5!) unique combinations. Web is full of examples.

Comment: That's why I am here can you solved thank you?

Comment: If you want someone to do the job for you - you are in the wrong place. We are here to answer specific questions.

Comment: Don't be tough on me as my dad man tough love is not the thing right now but thank you so much I just found the answers on the web I guess the toughness of my father was useful after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new array of seen text then check if seen text exists in array then call again function:

```js
var used = [];

function shuffle(array) {
let currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

//             While there remain elements to shuffle...
while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}
if (used.includes(array.join(""))) {
    array = shuffle(d);
}
used.push(array.join(""));
return array;
}

let d = ["d", "e", "a", "d"];

var x = setInterval(function() {
try {
    console.log(shuffle(d).join(""))
} catch (e) {
    clearInterval(x);
}
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Intelligent dudes always light up the room always.

Answer (score 0):

And another beautiful way u can do it as well

```
       function getAllPermutations(string) {
        let results = [];

          if (string.length === 1) {
        results.push(string);
       return results;
          }

     for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var firstChar = string[i];
       var charsLeft = string.substring(0, i) + string.substring(i + 1);
       var innerPermutations = getAllPermutations(charsLeft);
      for (var j = 0; j < innerPermutations.length; j++) {
          results.push(firstChar + innerPermutations[j]);
      }
         }
       return results;
      }

       let d = getAllPermutations("dead").filter(function(item,pos,self){
       return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
        })

        console.log(d)
```